# There is way to save only part of the string object into async-storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

There is way to save only part of the string object into async-storage ?
for example if inside the "result.userPrincipalName" it save " bob23@hotmail.com "
so i want it will be save only the "bob23" , so what is the way to do it ?

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'AZURE-USERNAME',
          JSON.stringify(
            result.userPrincipalName.substring(0, data.indexOf('@'))
          )
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You condo something like this.

You can remove part of the string after a certain character.

As I can see in the documentation. It stores as a key-value pair.

So I made changes

```
let data = JSON.stringify(result.userPrincipalName);

//here substring will remove characters after and including `@` 
data = data.substring(0, data.indexOf('@'));
await AsyncStorage.setItem('AZURE-USERNAME', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to handle your desirable data on top level (add new input to user / new field in db with desired data etc. I don't know whereby you get your `userPrincipalName`).

But, if it's not possible, you can follow something like this:

```
const name = result.userPrincipalName.split('@')[0];

if (!name) throw new Error('Invalid email');

await AsyncStorage.setItem('AZURE-USERNAME', name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use **`split`** function in Javascript. [More information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
//Split the mame using split function
const splitName = result.userPrincipalName.split("@");

//Get the split value and save it
//After you splitting [0] mean first character set
const name = splitName[0];

//Save it to AsyncStorage
await AsyncStorage.setItem("AZURE-USERNAME", JSON.stringify(name));
```